# Using App inventor app to mail from google app engine

Tags: android, google-app-engine, app-inventor

Using Shival wolfs WolfWebEmail2 in app inventor to send mail via Google app engine and nothing arriving in recipient email.

need to confirm if my code is correct.

not showing any errors on app engine.

Does this look correct for command to run webapp?

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage), ('/sendemail', sendemail), ('/attach', attachfile)], debug=True)
def main():
  run_wsgi_app(application)
```

Think i have got a bit of small keyboard large finger syndrome.

Many thanks in advance.

OK Zig. Many thanks. Here it is

```
class sendemail(webapp.RequestHandler):

  def process_email(self, data):
outvalue=""
ValidData = False
logging.info("data: %s" %data)
details=data.split("|||")
data = "\"%s\"" %data
if len(details) == 5 or len(details) == 7:
  message = mail.EmailMessage()
  message.sender = EmailFrom
  NewAuthKey = details[0]
  EmailTo = details[1]
  EmailSubject = details[2]
  EmailBody = details[3]
  EmailBody = EmailBody.replace("\\t","\t")
  if details[4].lower()=="yes" and len(details) == 7:
    filename=details[5];
    file_id=details[6];
  ValidData = True

if ValidData:
  if NewAuthKey == AuthKey:
    logging.info("Auth Key Valid")
  else:
    logging.info("Auth Key does not Match")
    outvalue = "Auth Key is Invalid"
    ValidData = False

if ValidData:
  if mail.is_email_valid(EmailTo):
    message.to = EmailTo
  else:
    logging.info("Email Address for TO Address is Invalid")
    outvalue = "Email Address for TO Address is Invalid"
    ValidData = False

if ValidData:
  if len(EmailBody) > 0 and len(EmailSubject) > 0:
    message.subject = EmailSubject
    message.body = EmailBody
  else:
    logging.info("Subject or Body was Empty")
    outvalue = "Subject or Body was left Empty"
    ValidData = False

if ValidData:
  if details[4].lower()=="yes":
    try:
       filedata = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM emailattach WHERE id = :1 LIMIT 1",file_id).get()
       if filedata:
         message.attachments = [(filename, filedata.blob)]
    except Exception, message:
      ValidData = False
      logging.info("Could not attach file:\n\n "+str(message))
      outvalue = "Could not attach file:\n\n "+str(message)

if ValidData:
  try:
    message.send()
    logging.info("Email Sent")
    outvalue = "Email Sent"
if details[4].lower()=="yes":   ##delete the file once emailed
      key = db.GqlQuery("SELECT __key__ FROM emailattach where id = :1", file_id).get()
      if key:
        db.run_in_transaction(dbSafeDelete,key)

  except Exception, message:
    logging.info(message)
    outvalue = str(message)

self.response.out.write(outvalue)
```

I hope thats it! new to this.

Answer (score 0):

You've left out the last part of the boiplerplate:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Without it, the first request to each instance won't be processed.

Comment: Thanks Nick. That code is there after the run request. I will post the sendmail function for Zig to comment on.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us the sendemail function?

**EDIT**

message.sender = EmailFrom

> Where is EmailFrom?

Try removing all the validations and check if the email gets sent.

First try running this-

```
message = mail.EmailMessage(sender="you@domain.com",
                            subject="Testing")
message.to = "you@domain.com"
message.body = "This is the body!"
message.send()
```

Change both email addresses to your email.

If it works then check the validation and other parts one at a time.

Comment: sorry new to stackoverflow and trying to post code in wrong place i think

Comment: added above. If you see what i see its what i got in the main.py file.

Comment: Thankyou Zig. I will play with it some more. Am beginning to understand what the Python code does and can see that the request from the app seems to get lost in the app engine somehow.